# CreateProcess only executes the half command

Tags: c++, system, createprocess

I have a problem with CreateProcess. I have create the following Source Code:

```
STARTUPINFOA si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

CreateProcessA(nullptr,
    "plink.exe -telnet -P 9999  192.168.230.75 < C:\\Users\\Mahre\\Scripts\\Telenet_Script.txt",
    nullptr,//security
    nullptr,// security
    FALSE,//inherits handles
    0,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    &si,
    &pi);

WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

The problem is that CreateProcess executes the command only in half. The command `plink.exe -telnet -P 9999  192.168.230.75` is executed, but CreateProcess ignore this part `< C:\\Users\\Mahre\\Scripts\\Telenet_Script.txt`. I'm pretty sure it's the less than sign.

With the evil `system()` it works very well and it was execute the complete command:

```
system("plink.exe -telnet -P 9999  192.168.230.75 < C:\\Users\\Mahre\\Scripts\\Telenet_Script.txt");
```

Can someone explain to me how I can do this with the CreateProcess?

Comment: Look into executing cmd.exe instead.

Comment: CreateProcess() does not know anything about input redirection.  That's a shell feature, execute cmd.exe /c instead.

Comment: I could imagine that `<` and `C:\\Users\\Mahre\\Scripts\\Telenet_Script.txt` are passed to `telnet` as arguments as well, and `telnet` processes them somehow or just ignores them. That's in opposition to calling this line in `bash` or `cmd.exe` where the part after `<` is processed by `bash` or `cmd.exe` itself (as input redirection like already mention by @HansPassant).

Answer (score 3):

The input redirection operator is provided by the shell, in this case `cmd.exe`.

To do this with `CreateProcess()`, you need to do this yourself.

First open the file you want to use as input for reading using `CreateFile()` and set the handle to be inheritable. When you call `CreateProcess()`, you need to set the inheritable handles flag to TRUE, and fill in the `STARTUPINFO` struct to contain the handle you want to use for standard input.

When doing it this way, you should not provide the "< filename" part of the command because you have set that up by hand.

For more information, read the `CreateProcess` documentation on MSDN. The are examples in the documentation covering variants on this case.